# Oscillation detection of a signal in python

Tags: python

I am trying to detect oscillation in a signal resulting from a step command.

The signals I am dealing with look like these:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I was wondering if anyone could suggest some python tools/libraries to use to detect oscillations. I would like to have/build a tool able to say:

- "this signal is oscillating and I am XX% confident about it".
- "this signal is not oscillating and I am XX% confident about it".

Even just pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using a Fourier transform could help detecting oscillations.

Comment: Take a look at [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). You can do fine grained specification of what you consider a "peak" and then based on the peaks and their distance you can decide whether it's oscillating or not.

Comment: Thanks, looking on the internet these were the main approaches I was looking at but did not know if I was making the problem more complex than it is. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I will first try with the peaks suggestion (I was actually using MATLAB function `findPeaks` to get started, I am more proficient in MATLAB than python) and if that approach does not work I will switch to the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

I found windowed Fourier transforms good enough for these kind of problems. Scipy has an implementation of [short time Fourier transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#scipy.signal.stft).

The link has code examples that I won't reproduce here.

A global Fourier might be misleading if the signal starts oscillating then dampens below the noise level. In that case the Fourier signal will still show the early frequencies. This motivates the windowed transforms.

If you choose STFT make sure you use the magnitude of the STFT. Also be aware of the size of the windows. There are some Heissenberg uncertainty tradeoffs

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will keep it in mind and try to test also the function you mentioned.